# My model does not stay constant when I try to make it levitate up/down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

people of the stack overflow. I wanted to make a drone game for my personal project for school. Everything has been going well but I am facing a problem now. My script for my drone won't makes the drone stay at a constant height when I press the selected button. In other words when I press E or Q the drone goes continuously up or continuously down. I want it to go up as long as I am pressing the selected key. How would I do that?

code ->

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Levitating : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody ourDrone;

private void Awake()
{
    ourDrone = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Make the drone default velocity the same value of the gravity acceleration, with opposite direction
private Vector3 DRONE_DEFAULT_VELOCITY = new Vector3(0, 9.81f, 0);

public float upForce;

private void Update()
{
    MovementUpDown();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    ourDrone.AddRelativeForce(DRONE_DEFAULT_VELOCITY * upForce);
}

void MovementUpDown()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        upForce = 15;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        upForce = -3;
    }
    else
    {
        // Resetting the force muultiplier
        upForce = 1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Since you're using physics, you could increase both the drag and the moving force on the rigidbody.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly`c#`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your physics are wrong.
In the default mode (upForce = 1) you're cancelling out gravity so no acceleration will be applied to your rb.
However, when you're pressing one of your control buttons, you're adding a force, and thus, per Newtons law, you're adding an acceleration, which will result in a velocity that will persist even after you've stopped pressing the button.
Now, I don't know exactly why you've modeled it as you have, but the easiest solution to your problem would be to disable gravity on your rigidbody and modify the velocity of the rb directly. Or use a different forceMode in your AddForce. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html use Velocity change.

If you want to model an actual drone, as one would in real life, you should look into control systems, such as PID, but that might be overkill.

Best of luck